# Почему не работает минус?

Tags: python, калькулятор

Когда при проверке ввожу минус вылезает это Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dotin\Documents\test.py", line 23, in 
print("Результат: " + str (c))
NameError: name 'c' is not defined

```
    # Калькулятор

from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

# use Colorama to make Termcolor work on Windows too
init()

print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.GREEN )

what = input( "Что делаем? (+, -)" )

print( Back.RED )

a = float( input("Введи первое число: ") )
b = float( input("Введи второе число: ") )

print( Back.CYAN )

if what == "+":
    c = a + b
print("Результат: " + str (c))
if what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print("Результат: " - str (c))

input()
```

Comment: `print` должен быть на том же уровне что и `с = a + b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if what == "+":
    c = a + b
print("Результат: " + str (c))
```

В этом фрагменте кода, если `if` не сработал, то значение `c` будет неопределённым при печати, на что и ругается интерпретатор. Как правильно написал Danis в комментарии, тут неправильный отступ у `print`. Про остальное вам в другом ответе написали.

Answer (score 3):

```
print("Результат: " - str (c))
```

вы так строки складываете?
для сложения строк надо `+` использовать

и кстати используйте уже питон 21 века :), а именно f-строки:

```
if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print(f"Результат: {c}")

if what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print(f"Результат: {c}")
```

Comment: Это ценное замечание, но конкретно на вопрос оно никак не отвечает.